# scraping onclick

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to scrape the reviews on this webpage.

http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g294265-d2309275-Reviews-The_Forest_by_Wangz-Singapore.html

The only problem in each review is "*More*", which loads more text on OnClick event.

For example:

```
<span class="taLnk hvrIE6 tr147826763 moreLink" onclick = " ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(2247); ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.expandReviews', event,this,'review_147826763', '1', 2247)">
More </span>
```

How to scrap the complete review text using LXML/BeautifulSoup?

Comment: The page uses JavaScript to load that extra information through AJAX. Use the browser developer tools to determine what URLs are called for such links, then call those links directly from your Python code.

Comment: Sometimes the JavaScript will not call links but global objects instead. In this case you need to use a JavaScript based scraper. I'd suggest PhantomJS.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: @JRM: PhantomJS no longer provides Python bindings; [`ghost.py`](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) would do though.

Comment: @Vino: Explaining in detail could end up requiring a book, a little more than I have space and time for here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Cool. Thanks. I am going to try Selenium WebDriver and PhantonJS. Hope I am heading in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the kind of answer you're looking for, but I've started looking at PhantomJS, which gives you a headless, scriptable, webkit browser. I'd bet it's an easier path than whatever ajax reverse engineering rabbit hole you're about to go down...

Comment: PhantomJS no longer provides Python bindings; [`ghost.py`](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) would do though.

Comment: @Ross M Karchner Thanks. I will try PhantomJS.